# function template getting : conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast error

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

i have function template which looks like this :

HelloWorld.h

```
template<typename T>
    bool NodeTraverse(T* &pGameObj);
```

HelloWorld.cpp

```
template<typename T>
bool HelloWorld::NodeTraverse(T* &pGameObj)
{
}
```

im passing to the function 2 types 
sometimes A_object and Somtimes B_obejct both are implementing same interface IGame

```
class IGame
{
public:
    virtual ObjType getType() = 0;
    virtual void setType(ObjType ot) = 0;

protected:
    ObjType objtype;


};
```

class A_object : public IGame
{
public:
    A_object();
    ObjType getType() { return objtype; }
    void setType(ObjType ot) { objtype = ot; }
}

```
class A_object : public IGame
{
public:
    A_object();
    virtual ~A_object();
    ObjType getType() { return objtype; }
    void setType(ObjType ot) { objtype = ot; }
}

class B_object : public IGame
{
public:
    B_object();
    virtual ~B_object();
    ObjType getType() { return objtype; }
    void setType(ObjType ot) { objtype = ot; }
}
```

now i call NodeTraverse like this :

```
A_object * pA_object = new A_object() ;
pA_object ->setType(A_OBJECT);

NodeTraverse(pA_object);
```

so far all good . 
but when i compile the app im getting this worrying

```
2>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
2>          d:\\classes\helloworldscene.cpp(114) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool HelloWorld::NodeTraverse<A_object >(T *&)' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              T=A_object 
2>          ]
```

But the problem is that im allso getting **compilation** error which i suspect related when i do this :

```
if (gameObjParent->getType() == LAYER_OBJECT)
{
    pGameObj = ((A_object *)gameObjParent);
}
else if (gameObjParent->getType() == SPRITE_OBJECT)
{
    pGameObj = ((B_object *)gameObjParent);  // HERE IS THE COMPILATION ERROR 
}
```

some how it thinks that gameObjParent is A_object *
This is the error:
it comes above the template worning

```
2>d:\classes\helloworldscene.cpp(200): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'B_object *' to 'A_object *'
2>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
2>          d:\\classes\helloworldscene.cpp(114) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool HelloWorld::NodeTraverse<A_object >(T *&)' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              T=A_object 
2>          ]
```

the wired part is that it is compilation error . why ?

Comment: Post a minimal example, right now we have to guess where which piece of code is supposed to be...

Comment: Generally speaking, whenever you find the need to do a C-style cast you're probably doing something you should not do. In this case I suggest you first look if you can't solve your *original* problem with polymorphism and virtual functions.

Comment: HelloWorld **.cpp** is a suspicious place to implement template method.

Comment: what do you mean cpp it wired place ?

Comment: It seems that your implementation only see forward declaration of `A_object`/`B_object` and not full definition (with inheritance with `IGame`).

Comment: Look at [why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: i was looking on this post , but when i do for example : 
bool HelloWorld::NodeTraverse<A_object * >(T* &pGameObj)
it doesn't work

Comment: @Some programmer dude
this is what i did , didnt know its so problematic